# how to start the container automatically when its stopped?--AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, containers, dockerfile

I have the docker container with jar file to run and i run the container by

```
sudo docker run --name xxx -d imagename
```

after the jar file was run successfully,then the container became inactive condition.

I want to restart the container automatically in amazon web service .

Comment: Could you please share the entire command you are using to run container. How you are executing the jar file? where is the command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `restart policies` Docker provides. Maybe that is the solution for you?
[Docker Restart Policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/restart-policies-restart)